# Regex to validate italian names from text java

Tags: java, regex

So i want to validate italian names. They can be something like this Angelo Oreste Adrisano, Ferruccio Resta, Antonio De Falchi, Tamara Donà, Gianfranco D'Angelo or Clelia D'Onofrio. Can someone please help me out.
My approach is: [A-Z][a-z]{1,13} [A-Z][a-z]{1,13}( [A-Z][a-z]{1,13})?

It works with names like Angelo Oreste Adrisano and such but i want to include also names like  Clelia D'Onofrio and Tamara Donà.

The question is NOT about NER(Named Entity Recognition)! In other words for me is acceptable for example "Scuola Di Nasia" which is not a real name...

Comment: I'm not sure your current regex pattern would pick up on accented characters.

Comment: do you have a list of names to check against?

Comment: How would you expect a regex to distinguish between words like `Toggle` or `Scuola` and actual names that can come in arbitrary form? As an extreme example let's say you want to do that for any name, how would you distinguish between `joy` and `Joy`, especially if the former is the first word in a sentence? - What I'm trying to get at: regex are not really good at helping you to find names as opposed to nouns.

Comment: On the other hand: how did you apply that regex and what results would you expect?

Comment: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @Anouar yes how to do that? other then that i need a more general pattern maybe pretested on some Italian names

Answer (score 1):

Regex is a bit of a blind tool. It doesn't really understand context. To a regex of **[a-zA-Z ]*** these are all valid :

- New York
- Corgi
- Throwing
- egg
- Quickly

That's an incredibly simple regex, but notice how it doesn't distinguish at all between names, nouns, verbs, and adjectives.

Unless you're hard-coding in the Strings of what a valid name (by human definitions) is, as far as I know, all regexes will just pick up any jumble of characters that match what you've written. At that point, you may as well just make a list of valid names yourself.

Your regex, as it is written, will match any sequence of two to three words, each starting with a capital letter from A-Z, followed by up to thirteen lowercase letters from a-z. That description alone doesn't exclude things such as "Adfnwj Jsdako Mvdso" and, to my knowledge, regex can't do so simply.

Comment: The question is not about NER. I edited the question.

Comment: @DrunkCat My apologies, I'm confused. Is this question regarding the accents included in the names? As far as I know, there is no formal definition of what constitutes a "valid", specifically Italian, name. You could specify some common consonant-vowel pairs with optional characters, but you'd then be restricting to a subset of what your definition of a "valid" name might be. If that's ok, you could try that, but it wouldn't capture the **entire** domain of "all possible names which are, or seem to be, Italian in origin". Is there any way you could make your needs clearer?